# Como puedo hacer que el Link de React Router Dom me abra en otra pagina distinta y no en la misma de inicio?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, routerlink

Estuve viendo tutoriales y utilizan Switch y Router y otros que mi Visual Studio Code no me permite. Mi problema no es con un enlace dinamico sino que cuando creo un Link con Router Dom en vez de abrir pagina nueva me lo compila arriba de la pagina principal... tambien actualice la ultima version de node y no eso. como lo puedo solucionar? Aqui el codigo

App

```
import Portada from './components/Principal';
import './App.css';
import { Routes, Route, BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import CurriculumCV from './components/CurriculumCV';
import React from 'react';


function App() {


  return (

   <BrowserRouter>
  
  
<Routes>
    <Route exact path='/curriculum' element={<CurriculumCV/>}/>
</Routes>

    <Portada />
   
   </BrowserRouter>
```

NavBar

```
import './style.css';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';


function Navigation() {
    return(
        <Navbar expand="lg">
        <Container>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="me-auto">
              <Nav.Link style={{fontFamily: 'notoRegular'}} href="#sobre">Sobre</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link style={{fontFamily: 'notoRegular'}} href="#cursos">Cursos</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link style={{fontFamily: 'notoRegular'}} href="#t">Algunos </Nav.Link>
              <Link to='/curriculum' preventScrollReset={true} style={{textDecoration: 'none'}} ><Nav.Link href='#curriculum' style={{fontFamily: 'notoRegular'}}>Curriculum</Nav.Link></Link>

             
            <Nav.Link style={{fontFamily: 'notoRegular'}} href="#c">C</Nav.Link>
             
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
        
        
    );

}

export default Navigation;
```

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar un poco más? Solo dejaste el código pero no entiendo qué es lo que quieres hacer en tu navigation.

Answer (score 1):

Agrega esto `target="_blank"` dentro de la etiqueta de `Link` deberia funcionarte asi

```js
<Link to='/curriculum' target="_blank" preventScrollReset={true} style={{textDecoration: 'none'}} ><Nav.Link href='#curriculum' style={{fontFamily: 'notoRegular'}}>Curriculum</Nav.Link></Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregarle `target="_blank"` dentro del tag Link para que te cargue la página en una nueva pestaña, si es que entendí lo que quieres realizar.